# Trying to add Array of Strings via Another Class using HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

Basically I know how to do this with ArrayList but to do it with Array i'm totally stumped.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Collection;

public class NobelPrizeWinners
{
    private HashMap<String, PrizeWinners[]> winners;

    public NobelPrizeWinners()
    {
        winners = new HashMap<String, PrizeWinners[]>();

        PrizeWinners[] name = new PrizeWinners[3];
        name[0] = new PrizeWinners("hey" , "Hey");

        winners.put("2008", name);
    }
}
public void displayAllYearsAndWinners(){
    Set<String> years = winners.keySet();

            for(String year : years){
                PrizeWinners [] list = winners.get(year);
                for(PrizeWinners[] names : list){

               System.out.println(year + " " +   names); 
            }

         }

   }
```

This returns only the memory address not the actual Strings (The PrizeWinners class has two String Parameters in the Constructor, as well as two set methods for first and last name)

I feel like i'm pretty close as it returns "2008" three times but only the memory address or null the other three times (as I haven't added the other 2 arrays yet still testing to see if it even works)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like its a name or a method that I need to call that i'm not sure on.

Comment: When what returns?  Where is your `return` statement?

Comment: I have a separate method that prints the name in the middle of two for each loops, so I guess its not actually return as much as printing through a System.out.println and when it prints it out it prints the memory address.

Comment: You should include that method as well.

Comment: Okay i'll edit it right now

Comment: I put the Method in there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the loop should be the following:

```
for (String year: years) {
    PrizeWinners[] list = winners.get(year);
    for (PrizeWinners names: list) {
        System.out.println(year + " " + names);
    }
}
```

Because you already retrieve `list` as an array, your for-each loop returns a `PrizeWinners` each iteration, not **another array**.

This line:

```
System.out.println(year + " " +   names);
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
System.out.println(year.toString() + " " +   names.toString());
```

Since `year` is a `String`, its `toString()` method simply returns its value, as expected.

But `names` is an `Array`. Its `toString()` method is directly inherited from `Object` and prints the memory address of `names`.

The cleanest way to solve this is to override `toString()` in the class `PrizeWinners`. This lets you decide for yourself what the `String` representation of your class should be.

```
public String toString() {
    return this.firstName + ", " + this.lastName;
}
```

Now, when the implicit `toString()` is called on the `names` instance of `PrizeWinners`, you'll get your expected output.

Comment: I get an incompatible types message: PrizeWinners cannot be converted to PrizeWinners[] its showing list as a reason why

Comment: Desired output would be for it to display the year and a first and last name.

Comment: Weird it actually would compile and let me print out the memory address and now it won't even when I return it to the original way I wrote it

Comment: I took out the second PrizeWinners[] and just put PrizeWinners in the 2nd for each loop

Comment: I retype Arrays.toString back in for the names and I get a "no suitable method found for toString PrizeWinners.

Comment: It should actually print the year in String, which it does, and then the String "hey", "hey" as one String is what I was going for.

Comment: 2008 PrizeWinners@19c9634

Comment: This works, but I have another question, is there another way to change that object to string by declaring an object obj type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `toString()` method by definition returns the `String` representation of an object. The best solution is to override its functionality in your own class. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
     for(String year : years){
        PrizeWinners [] list = winners.get(year);
        for(PrizeWinners winnerName: list){
              System.out.println(year + " " +   winnerName.firstName + " " + winnerName.lastName); 

        }

     }
```

Comment: I get PrizeWinners cannot be converted to PrizeWinners[]

Answer (score 1):

You have some weird stuff going on in your displayAllYearsAndWinners method. It can be simplified to just this:

**NobelPrizeWinners.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NobelPrizeWinners {
  private Map<String, PrizeWinner[]> yearToWinners;

  public NobelPrizeWinners() {
    yearToWinners = new HashMap<String, PrizeWinner[]>();

    PrizeWinner[] winners2008 = new PrizeWinner[3];
    winners2008[0] = new PrizeWinner("hey", "Hey");
    yearToWinners.put("2008", winners2008);
  }

  public void displayAllYearsAndWinners() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, PrizeWinner[]> entry : yearToWinners.entrySet()) {
      System.out.printf("%s %s%n", entry.getKey(), Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
    }
  }
}
```

Your `PrizeWinners` class should probably not be plural if each object represents a single winner. You are using a `PrizeWinner` array to represent multiple prize winners.

Notice that `toString` is overridden.

**PrizeWinner.java**

```
public class PrizeWinner {
  private String first;
  private String last;

  public PrizeWinner(String first, String last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %s", first, last);
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
2008 [hey Hey, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void displayAllYearsAndWinners(){
    Set<String> years = winners.keySet();
            for(String year : years){
                PrizeWinners [] list = winners.get(year);
                for(PrizeWinners prizeWinners : list){
                   System.out.println(year + " " +   prizeWinners.first+" "+ prizeWinners.last); 
            }
         }
   }
```